# Is the Euclidean norm the unique norm which turns $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a Banach space?

Tags: banach-spaces

See the title. Essentially I'm wondering if the answer is no, does there exist two inequivalent notions of calculus on $\mathbb{R}^n$ obtained via the Frechet derivative for the two resulting (inequivalent) Banach Spaces.

Comment: If all norms over $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent, then what is the inequivalence (of Banach spaces) you are referring to?

Comment: @Ranc I mean in the case where the norms are not equivalent

Comment: But they are always equivalent. This is a standard result for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Ranc I realise now you're referring to an actual result "all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent", sorry, I was actually unaware of this fact (revising Banach spaces after a very long time away from them)

Comment: In fact, we have even a slightly stronger result. Every finite dimensional normed space is a Banach space (this is can be proven using the fact that all norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent).

Comment: @Ranc If you rewrite the statement that all of the norms are equivalent as an answer, I will accept it. (Thank you for clarifying this for me btw)

Comment: @Okazaki it's ok :). Just wasn't sure if you needed this or something else.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven GREAT point, Severin and people usually don't point this out in elementary analysis courses that use Banach spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or any other finite-dimensional normed space) are equivalent, and so if a sequence converges or is a Cauchy sequence under one norm, so it does or is in any other. In particular, any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ turns it into a Banach space.

Comment: A banach space is a complete normed space, completeness is not a topological property, so your point is not very well made (the sentence "in particular" does not apply)

Comment: True; I made the formulation more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Let $||.||_a$ be another norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$ .

We know that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in every finite dimensional space all the norms are equivalent, i.e:$$\exists C,D>0 :C||x||_a \leqslant ||x||_2 \leqslant D||x||_a, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

Where $||.||_2$ is the euclideian norm.

Now let $\{v_1,v_2...v_n\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a Cauchy sequence with respect to the norm $||.||_a$. Note that $x_m=x_m^{(1)}v_1+...+x_m^{(n)}v_n$

We have that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists m_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||x_s-x_l||_a< \epsilon, \forall s,l \geqslant m_0$

Using the inequality of the equivalence of norms you can see that $x_m$ is a cauchy sequence with respect to the euclideian norm and because of the completeness of $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the euclideian norm we have that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||x_m-x||_2 \rightarrow 0$ and $x=x_1v_1+...+x_nv_n$

Again from the inequality of the equivalence of norms you can see that $||x_m-x||_a \rightarrow 0$.

Therefore $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete with respcet to the norm $||.||_a$

Also you have to know that completeness is not preserved under homeomorphisms but it is preserved under isometries.